# How to reference Other Sections in a document

Tags: technical-writing

I am writing a procedure and want to reference other sections in the same procedure.  What is the correct way to call them out?  Example: The xxxx are shown in Section V, Procedures Used to Implement the Process.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your Hierarchy, there are various styles to this, but here are a few rules:

- Start from the top, always lead with the top section. If there is no sorting level higher than Section, always lead with section.
- Abbreviated citation is simple when you know the starting point. 5.1 would to me clearly indicate section five question one.
- Ensure that the section headings have numbers next to them to make this clear.

Anyway works as long as you are consistent. I've seen in the California civil code, something like: Part - section - sub-section - paragraph - sentence.

Just be consistent with the order, terminology, and if you abbreviate, the punctuation.